# The Struts dispatcher cannot be found. (while running in strut2)

Tags: struts2

I started implementing "hello world" program in struts2 but got following error on running the web application:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

Files of my project are:

**index.jsp**

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        
        <s:property value="msg" default="guest"></s:property>
        <s:form action="demostrutsclass">
            <s:textfield name="username"></s:textfield>
            <s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```html
<%--
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        
        <s:property value="msg" default="guest"></s:property>
        <s:form action="demostrutsclass">
            <s:textfield name="username"></s:textfield>
            <s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
--%>
```

**struts.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<struts>

    <package name="pak" extends="struts-default">
        
        <action name="demostrutsclass" class="pak.demostrutsclass" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**demostrutsclass.java**

```html
package pak;

public class demostrutsclass {
    
    private String username;
    private String msg;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    
    public String execute(){
        msg = "hi, "+username;
        return "success";
    }
    
}
```

All essential libraries from struts-2.5.26 are already added.

Answer (score 0):

> This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. **Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag.**

You are likely hitting `index.jsp` without an associated action. Since your `index.jsp` page has S2 tags, there must be an action.

There are multiple solutions; which makes the most sense depends on your needs. You can either have `index.jsp` *not* use S2 tags, or you can set up your welcome page to be an action instead of a "raw" JSP.